# Google Sheets: Extract Username from Hyperlinked Email Adress

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a spreadsheet with over 20+ users and most users will type their full name and hyperlink their name to their email address. Is it possible to extract and just grab their username (e.g. kennysmith01@ jenniferle023@)?

[Example Google Sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A9Vp75h0dQWY93wCpYJmLm2A-1QmINtGtfnWSRd5TWA/edit#gid=0)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your following question,

> Is it possible to extract and just grab their username (e.g. kennysmith01@ jenniferle023@)?

I think that it's yes. In your situation, how about using Google Apps Script? When Google Apps Script is used, a sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your provided Spreadsheet. And, please confirm the sheet name and the range of a1Notation. And, save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";
  const a1Notation = "A2:A4";

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const rv = sheet.getRange(a1Notation).getRichTextValues();
  const res = rv.map((r, i) => r.map((c, j) => {
    return {
      row: i + 1,
      column: j + 1,
      names: c.getRuns().reduce((ar, s) => {
        const link = s.getLinkUrl();
        if (link) {
          ar.push(link.replace("mailto:", "").split("@")[0]);
        }
        return ar;
      }, [])
    }
  }));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run to your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained. This value can be seen in the log.

```json
[
  [{"row":1,"column":1,"names":["ke###","je###"]}],
  [{"row":2,"column":1,"names":["ja###"]}],
  [{"row":3,"column":1,"names":["je###","ro###"]}]
]
```

If you want to add `@` to the retrieved value, please modify the above script as follows.

##### From

```js
ar.push(link.replace("mailto:", "").split("@")[0]);
```

##### To

```js
ar.push(link.replace("mailto:", "").split("@")[0] + "@");
```

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalues)
- [Class RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

### ALTERNATE SOLUTION

We can use a custom formula to achieve extracting the usernames from the hyperlinked email addresses. First, we'll be using [Google Apps Script](https://script.google.com) to create the custom formula, which you can open on your Google Sheets by clicking on **Extensions > Apps Script.**

**You can use this sample script below for your reference:**

```
/**
* A custom formula function that returns the usernames
* of the hyperlinked email addresses
* @param {cell} the cell index where the hyperlinked emails are located (e.g. A1)
* @return the usernames of the hyperlinked email addresses
* @customfunction
*/
function usernameExtract(cell) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");  // you can change the sheet name to where the data
  // will actually be located
  var data = ss.getRange(`${cell}`).getRichTextValue().getRuns(); // this gets the styling of the text on that cell (e.g hyperlinks)
  var str = [];
  var out = [];
  var regExp = /([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@/;
  // extracts the usernames from the URLs
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var ex = regExp.exec(data[i].getLinkUrl());
    if (ex != null)
      str.push(ex[0]);
  }
  // creates the output string
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (!i)
      out[0] = str[i];
    else
      out[0] += ", " + str[i];
  }

  return out;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use this part of the script if you want to only get the username, without the @ sign:

```
  var regExp = /mailto:([^@]+)@/;
  // extracts the usernames from the URLs
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var ex = regExp.exec(data[i].getLinkUrl());
    if (ex != null)
      str.push(ex[1]);
  }
```

Once you have saved this script, you can proceed to enter the formula as you normally would on Google Sheets. However, for the formula input, **you will need to enclose the cell index in quotation marks**, so that the formula will read the links within the text, and not only the text values itself. (See output sample below)

For example: `=usernameExtract("A2")`

### OUTPUT

[image]

### REFERENCES

- [Class RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!